# Git Workflow Acquia Cloud and Acquia Dev desktop

Tags: 8, version-control, acquia-dev-desktop, acquia-cloud

I use *Acquia Cloud* and installed Drupal 8 and cloned this (origin) locally using *Acquia Dev desktop.*

1. To use *Dev Desktop* I think I'm able to develop the Front-end design
   faster, instead of committing the changes every time and push them
   to Acquia Cloud to see them in the browser. Am I right?
2. And will my client also be able to commit his code from his local branch
   to the Acquia Cloud repo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Working on the frontend isn't tied to using Acquia Dev Desktop or
   not. It's a personal preference to work locally by cloning a remote
   site and work on theming/frontend and commit changes periodically to
   the remote repo when you're happy with the changes you see in your browser. Some customers prefer working directly on the Acquia Cloud dev environment with [Livedev](https://docs.acquia.com/cloud/manage/code/livedev). Really, it's what you think is best for you.
2. Git is a decentralized version control system. It means both you and your client can checkout the Acquia Cloud repo and hold a live copy of the repo. You and your client can then commit/push code either to the default branch (`master`) or with a feature branch. This is by no means specific to Acquia Cloud. This is how git works. What matters is you `git pull` always before committing / pushing code, so that you can retrieve the changes your client has made on the current working branch (e.g. `master`). With a feature branch, it'll require you merge it back to e.g. `master` when it's ready. See https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Branches-in-a-Nutshell for details.